# Lookup Multiple Result with one criteria

Tags: excel

I am trying to find a function that can help me with this case!

```
ID Number   Wage 1  Wage 2  Wage 3  Wage 4  Wage 5
100                 
200
```

I'm looking for the function that can help me so I can fill the wage. The wage data will came from another sheet, for the example like this

```
ID Number   Wage
100          500
100          600
100          700
200          600
200          700
200          800
200          900
```

The procedure is I will insert the ID number, so the value of the wage will be shown automatically.

The case is :

For ID number 100, will get:

- 500 for wage 1,
- 600 for wage 2
- and 700 for wage 3.

For ID number 200, will get:

- 600 for wage 1,
- 700 for wage 2,
- 800 for wage 3
- and 900 for wage 4.

The number of wage can be vary up to 5.

Comment: can't u add one more column in wage data sheet which gives number (1,2,3,4,5) to the wages

Comment: Sorry, it can't. Because the database contain a lot of another data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$8=$D2,ROW($B$2:$B$8)-1),COLUMNS($D$2:D$2))),"")
```

Entered as an array formula, that is, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It's a bit complicated, but it:

- First checks for rows that match the ID number.
- From those that match, it returns their row numbers.
- `SMALL` takes the 1st, 2nd, etc depending on the number of columns since you entered the formula.
- `INDEX` takes these row numbers and returns the corresponding value.
- `IFERROR` handles instances where there is no appropriate value.

[Here's a GoogleSpreadsheet sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rn-1mQiIEXm_lSTiFW4cZCxrpaxbt4meU6DEWPSmRP8/edit?usp=sharing)

Except that it handles array formulae differently there. You have to put `ArrayFormula` for the array formula to work (or it automatically inserts it if you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) but otherwise, it's the same.

You only have to change the ranges as necessary.

Comment: @user3667535 What's the problem with the formula? I edited the spreadsheet example in the link in the answer to match the data that you just mentioned and see nothing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But in some case it goes error. For the example in case like this: 
ID Number Wage
100PA23         100
100PA23         200
100PA23         300
100PA23         400

In this case, if I use this formula, value in wage 1, wage 2, wage 3 and wage 4 goes wrong. I've try to fix it in several days but don't get good result. How can i fix this? 
Please help me 
Thanks for your concern

Comment: I try to use this formula from different file and sheet. 
When i try this formula, value in wage 1 will be 300 and value in wage 2 will be 400 but in wage 3 and wage 4 is zero.

Comment: @user3667535 Did you adjust the range? If there are more rows, you need to take those into consideration. I can't reproduce what you are describing since it's working fine for me.

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks for your attention

Comment: @user3667535 That's because you have to change the range too. And... because of that you have to change some things as well since there is no straightforward formula to do what you asked for. I edited the GSpreadsheet above for you to see. The blue cells are the ones that are relevant.

Comment: What is the meaning for this formula ROW($E$7:$E$13)-ROWS($A$1:$A$6) ?

Comment: @user3667535 `ROW()` gives the row number of the match. `ROWS()` gives the number number of rows of the range. Basically, the values start at row 2 in the grey cells, so you remove 1 to get the first value on the first row for `INDEX`. Since the ones in the blue box are further down, you need to remove more rows. That's why I used `ROWS()` here instead. I could have used a single number, but `ROWS()` makes it a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell under wage 1 is I7 and that's where you put your first formula, you can use the following array formula.

```
{=LARGE(IF($D$8:$D$11=$H8,$E$8:$E$11,""),1)}
```

It's a simple if function that is looking at $D$8:$D$11 for $H8 (which is 100 in this case). It then returns all of the wage results in an array (which you dont see).

The Large element and the ,1 at the end is then saying return the biggest number. In your formula under wage 2, change the formula so the 1 is a 2 (second largest) and then the next cell is 3 etc etc.

You must remember that when you paste this formula in, you cant hit enter, you have to hit enter so it becomes an array function.

So paste in

```
=LARGE(IF($D$8:$D$11=$H8,$E$8:$E$11,""),1)
```

then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and it'll become

```
{=LARGE(IF($D$8:$D$11=$H8,$E$8:$E$11,""),1)}
```